# Firebase reference as a prop problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So to start off, I am completely new to firebase. I am having a problem with the firebase reference. I think I'm putting it in the wrong spot. The error I'm getting says this: "Cannot read property 'database' of undefined"

I'm calling it in a constructor method like this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    rooms: []
  };
  this.roomsRef = this.props.firebase.database().ref('rooms');
}
```

And then the rest of the component is just setting the state of rooms like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.roomsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    const room = snapshot.val();
    room.key = snapshot.key;
    this.setState({ rooms: this.state.rooms.concat( room ) })
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't know where you're using `this.roomsRef`, but API calls are asynchronous. You might be trying to use `this.roomsRef` while it is still `undefined`

Comment: Do I at least have it in the right spot? I cant find anything in the firebase docs that help me.

Comment: Wait, it implies `this.props.firebase` is undefined when the constructor is run. Are you sure your firebase app is what's actually passed in? Try doing a direct import of your firebase setup, as opposed to passing it down through props, and see if that works

Comment: Figured it out, yeah I needed to add firebase as props to my <RoomList /> that's being rendered from the main component.

Comment: Awesome, glad you ended up figuring it out